# 2010 Access DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport wiping out query

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a simple statement in my vba:

```
    DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "ExportQueryModelDetailAllHistory"
```

The export is based on a query ("QueryModelDetailAllHistory").  It exports fields to an Excel workbook based on a query that INNER JOINS on table to another, taking fields from both tables.  For example:

```
Select Table1.Field1, Table1.Field2, Table2.Field2
   From Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Field1 = Table2.Field2;
```

When this command executes in vba it creates the workbook and then the saved query becomes:

```
SELECT;
```

Yet, when I manually run from the ExternalData/SavedExports it works great, running it multiple times.

For testing purposes, I exit the procedure immediately after the DoCmd.

Has anyone seen something like this (possible bug or am I doing something wrong?)?  Is there a workaround?

Comment: As a workaround I changed the DoCmd to:      

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "QueryModelDetailAllHistory", _
        fXLSXFile  

But if anyone has an idea of what is happening, that would be great.

Comment: Is that the only code that the process runs or is there something else in there? Based on what you've written so far, it should work perfectly fine as it is. But, perhaps there is something else in the rest of the code causing issues?

Comment: For testing I had removed all code that wasn't required to get to the DoCmd.  It's very strange, for sure.  Theoretically, the runsavedimportexport should have nothing to do with any other vba code, as it is (or should be) a task that does not interface with code.  It's only **supposed to** run the saved process and create the Excel book.